# $result=mysql_query($query) or die

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new in php and now I have problem to get result if i enter $h2 < $h1. If someone can help me finding where is my mistake and what would i add? I'm glad to know that..

```html
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $("#h1").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    $("#h2").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  } );
  </script>
```

```
if ($tag == 2 and $v1 != '') {

$startu=mktime($h1);
$endu=mktime($h2);

$starts=mktime($start);
$ends=mktime($end);

$diffs=$endu-$startu;
$diff=$end-$start;

if ($diffs > 0 || 1==1) {

  $query="update settings set cinemashow='$s1' where id=1";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die ('Failed to update');

  $query="update settings set start='$h1' where id=1";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die ('Failed to update');

  $query="update settings set end='$h2' where id=1";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die ('Failed to update');

  $tag=1;
  } 

if ($diff < 0){
print "<td valign=middle align=center>
        <a href=setting.php? onclick=\"return confirm('Failed to update. Please set date again?')\"></font></a>
        </td></tr>";
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do 3 update statements, you can update all the columns in a single query.

Comment: e.g., `update settings set cinemashow='$s1', start='$h1', end='$h2' where id=1`

Comment: `if ($diffs > 0 || 1==1)` will always succeed because `1==1` is always true. So it's ignoring `$diffs >0`.